# Se repite el dato fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta en SQL Server:

```
SELECT r.id_referencia
    ,t.id_tipo
    ,o.id_operacion
    ,p.id_provincia
    ,s.id_superfice
    ,pr.id_precio
    ,v.id_vendedor
    ,f.id_fecha
FROM vendedor v
JOIN Inmuebles i ON v.nombre_vendedor = i.vendedor
JOIN referencia r ON r.id_referencia = i.Referencia
JOIN Tipo t ON t.nombre_tipo = i.Tipo
JOIN operacion o ON o.nombre_operacion = i.Operacion
JOIN provincia p ON p.nombre_provincia = i.Provincia
JOIN superficie s ON s.superficie = i.Superficie
JOIN precio_venta pr ON pr.valor_venta = i.Precio_Venta
JOIN (
    SELECT f.id_fecha
    FROM (
        SELECT fecha_alta
            ,YEAR(fecha_alta) AS año
            ,MONTH(fecha_alta) AS mes
            ,DAY(fecha_alta) AS dia
            ,1 AS marca
        FROM inmuebles
    UNION
        SELECT fecha_venta
            ,YEAR(fecha_venta) AS año
            ,MONTH(fecha_venta) AS mes
            ,DAY(fecha_venta) AS dia
            ,2 AS marca
        FROM inmuebles
        ) AS fec
    JOIN fecha f ON fec.año = f.año
    WHERE fec.mes = f.mes
        AND fec.dia = f.dia
        AND fec.marca = f.marca
    ) AS tiempo
CROSS JOIN fecha f ON tiempo.id_fecha = f.id_fecha
ORDER BY r.id_referencia
```

Me muestra los datos como quiero pero en el campo `id_fecha` se me repite y me queda así la tabla:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| id_r | id_t  | id_o  | id_p  | id_s  | id_p  | id_v | id_fecha |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 1        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 2        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 3        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 4        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 5        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 6        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 7        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 8        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 9        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 10       |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 11       |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 12       |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 13       |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
```

¿Qué parte de la consulta está mal?

tiene que ser algo asi (los numeros que no pueden ser iguales son el id_r y el id_fecha)

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| id_r | id_t  | id_o  | id_p  | id_s  | id_p  | id_v | id_fecha |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 1    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 1        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 2    | 7     | 8     | 6     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 2        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 3    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 753   | 2994  | 5    | 3        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 4    | 7     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 9        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 5    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 586      |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 6    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 6        |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 7    | 4     | 2     | 1     | 252   | 2994  | 5    | 43       |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| 8    | 4     | 10    | 345   | 752   | 5694  | 8    | 87       |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Hola Osvaldo, bienvenido a [es.so], por lo que veo, el dato de la fecha no se repite, ¿estás seguro que el ejemplo es el adecuado?

Comment: lo que veo es que se repite la información de todos los campos menos el de la fecha. Deberías colocar un ejemplo de cómo quieres que se muestre la información en comparación a cómo se está mostrando actualmente.

Comment: la mayoria de los datos se pueden repetir,  los datos que tienen que ser unicos son el id_r y el id_fecha.

Comment: Sólo tienes que agregar esto casi al final, antes del `ORDER BY`: **`GROUP BY r.id_r, f_id_fecha`** de ese modo te agrupará los registros por esas dos columnas.

Answer (score 1):

Debes revisar el uso del CrossJoin y de consultas aninadas; crea para cada una, una consulta aparte y detecta qué relación es que te está iterando datos de más.

Si puedes mostrar datos y estructura para cada tabla fuera más fácil colaborarte.